How do I filter data in a React child component by passing parent entity's ID?
I have a simple JHipster project with two entities Person and Address (1:N). I have enabled entity filters by following instruction from this page  Filtering your entities . My goal to modify the Person-Detail React component so that the person's list of address is shown below person's details.
I added the following in person-detail.tsx
<Address personId={personEntity.id}/>

Also modified the the address.tsx file to define the parameter:
port const Address = (personId) => {

I am not sure how to pass this parameter to getEntities(?) so that when the parameter exists (called from Person detail page), it will only show Address list of that person. However, if the Address index pages is opened (i.e. from navbar), all addresses will be shown.
I tried createing new createAsyncThunk in address-reducer.ts. and calling from getAllEntities (in address.tsx) function by checking if personId parameter exists. However, it only works if I click sort headers. By default it is showing all addresses.

You please share more code? looking at which we can have idea about what you have done from your side.
